# Copy non-contiguous array values to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to solve this using named ranges, for and do loops, found functions that no longer exist in Excel.

I use an invoice and would like to save the customer contact data, what they bought, the prices paid, comments, etc. from each new invoice to a single separate workbook - in the next empty row for each new invoice/customer.

I've done this successfully just copying to a different sheet in the same workbook, but can't get it into a different workbook so I can have a separate file of just customer and sales data.

I will be working in the current invoice file which is opened as a new workbook from a template (MasterInvoice.xltm) with the macros. When the invoice is completed, use a button to copy an array of specific cells in an order that will place them in a different order in the data store workbook on the next empty row.

The copied data should paste into a single row in the order as listed.
The code below works within the same workbook but I have been unable to make something that works across workbooks:

```
Sub CopyCustomerData()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, cls

cls = Array("F5", "A11", "F6", "F7", "F11", "F13", "A12", 
"A13", "A14", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "C15", "F42", "F20", "A39")
With Sheets("Customers")
    LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(2, .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
        .Cells(LR, i + 1).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range(cls(i)).Value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

My target is `Workbooks.Open ("C:\bm\invoice\Customer_Database.xlsx")
With Sheets("CustomerData")`

My Source Workbook is `C:\bm\invoice\MasterInvoice1.xlsx`

After the copy/paste, I need to save & close the target workbook.

Comment: Just out of interest: which functions did you find that no longer exist in Excel?

Comment: what is `Sheets("Invoice")` ? to which `Workbook` does this `Worksheet` belong to ? how does Excel suppose to guess to which ? You didn't fully qualify your sheets. Try `Workbooks("YourWorkbookkName").Sheets("YourSheetName").Range`

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for keeping up with KPI's at work. I know there are other ways to do it, but this is what I found to work. Since the workbooks are in the same folder you can take the directory path from the current workbook and concatenate with back slash and the workbook name. I would comment out the save workbook line until you have the correct way to paste the information.

```
Dim wb as string
Dim ap as string

ap = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Since they are in the same folder
wb = ap & "\Customer_Database.xlsx"


'select you range and copy it like you have done ex. 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Your Range Here").Copy

Workbooks.Open(wb)
Workbooks("Customer_Database.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet_Name").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("Cell to paste date in").Paste
Workbooks("Customer_Database.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

**Edit1**: Use a Variable to define the new Workbook you open. Later, there is no need to use `Activate` to paste.

```
Dim DestWb  As Workbook
Dim WbName As String
Dim ap As String

ap = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Since they are in the same folder
WbName = ap & "\Customer_Database.xlsx"

' set the opened workbook to a workbook object
Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(WbName)

'select your range and copy it like you have done ex.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Your Range Here").Copy

With DestWb
    'directly paste
    .Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("Cell to paste date in").Paste
    .Close (True)
End With
```

EDIT: I went through and used your existing work and got this to work with two worksheets with the same names and it imported the data from the MasterInvoice1 workbook to Customer_Database. I think you were doing an export, but it should be easy to switch.

```
Sub CopyCustomerData()
'I ran this macro from the Customer_Database workbook and saved it as a macro enabled
'workbook. I think it should be saved in the workbook that you are going to be building
'and maintaining yourself. You can flip a few things around and get it to work from the
'MasterInvoice1 workbook if you would rather.

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim cls As Variant
Dim AP As String
Dim wbArray(1 To 4) As String

AP = ThisWorkbook.Path

'In my opion this will make it easier to open workbooks and to activate the workbooks.
wbArray(1) = AP & "\Customer_Database.xlsm"
wbArray(2) = AP & "\MasterInvoice1.xlsx"
wbArray(3) = "Customer_Database.xlsx"
wbArray(4) = "MasterInvoice1.xlsx"

cls = Array("F5", "A11", "F6", "F7", "F11", "F13", "A12", _
"A13", "A14", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "C15", "F42", "F20", "A39")

'Opens the workbook MasterInvoice1.xlsx, this format needs the full path.
Workbooks.Open (wbArray(2))
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Customers")
    LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(2, .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
        'Make sure that when you are refering to a sheet in another workbook
        'have Workbooks(otherWB) before it, or it will think you are looking for
        'that sheet in the same workbook.
        'Also this pastes the values in the next column starting on row 2.
        .Cells(LR, i + 1).Value = Workbooks(wbArray(4)).Sheets("Invoice").Range(cls(i)).Value
    Next i
End With
'This will close the MasterInvoice1.xlsx workbook.
Workbooks(wbArray(4)).Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: May I offer some upgrades to your code ? I'll add them to the bottom of your answer

Comment: That looks better! Thanks

Comment: I apparently didn't make it clear, or I just don't know enough to make this work. The open file (working in) and source is C:\bm\invoice\MasterInvoice1.xlsx, Sheet-Invoice  and the targeted closed file is Customer_Database.xlsx, Sheet-CustomerData in the same folder. I need to copy many individual cells (array) that are scattered over the spreadsheet as indicated in the first post. So I need to copy the array, open the target, paste into the next available row.

Comment: I was looking at this again and if the array going to change in size each time or will the cells that you want to copy always be the exact same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative without opening the source workbook using [external references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f#tblID0EEBAAEAAA) (not tested)

```
Sub CopyCustomerData()
    Dim w As Workbook, r As Range, s as String, a() As String

    s = " F5 A11 F6 F7 F11 F13 A12 A13 A14 D11 D12 D13 D14 C15 F42 F20 A39"
    a = Split(Trim(Replace(s, " ", " ='C:\bm\invoice\[MasterInvoice1.xlsx]Invoice'!")))

    Set w = Workbooks.Open("C:\bm\invoice\Customer_Database.xlsx")
    Set r = w.Worksheets("CustomerData").UsedRange

    Set r = r.Offset(r.Rows.Count).Resize(1, UBound(a) + 1)    ' last empty row
    r.Formula = a
    r.Value2 = r.Value2     ' optional to convert the formulas to values

    w.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```